# $post->ID incorrect within meta box

Tags: metabox

I have a meta box and I am trying to get the current post id however I am getting the ID of a different post. Is there another way to get the ID?

```
function global_notice_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'avent_event' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'global-notice',
            __( 'Event Attendees', 'sitepoint' ),
            'global_notice_meta_box_callback',
            $screen
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'global_notice_meta_box' );


function global_notice_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    wp_reset_postdata();

    // 1st Method - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM avent_event_guestlist WHERE event_id = '.$post->ID, OBJECT );

    print_r($post);
}
```

Comment: is something changing if you comment the call to `wp_reset_postdata` ?

Comment: No with or without it still returns the incorrect post id

Answer (score 0):

Use the global variable $post.  It is not specific to the Metabox, which is really just a portal for display.

```
 global $post;
 $PostId     = $post->ID;
```